# Add checkbox to the ckeditor toolbar to addClass/removeClass in img elements

Tags: ckeditor

I want to write a ckeditor plugin that adds a checkbox to the toolbar.

- When an img element is selected, the checkbox should reflect whether the image has a certain class or not.
- When something else than an image is selected, the checkbox should be
  disabled, or maybe invisible.
- When I check or uncheck the checkbox, the class should be added/removed to/from the img.

In other words, I want to add something else than a button to the toolbar (those that are added with editor.ui.addButton), and that something should be a checkbox.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it anyway, using editor.ui.add and editor.ui.addHandler. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

plugin.js:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('add_zoomable_to_image',
{
  init: function( editor )
  {
    var disabled_span_color = "#cccccc";
    var enabled_span_color = "#000000";

    var cb;
    var span;

    var html =
      "<div style='height: 25px; display: inline-block'>" +
          "<div style='margin: 5px'><input class='add_zoomable_cb' type='checkbox' disabled='disabled'>" +
              "<span class='add_zoomable_span' style='color: " + disabled_span_color + "'> Add zoomable to image</span>" +
          "</div>" +
      "</div>";

    editor.ui.add('add_zoomable_to_image', "zoomable_button", {});
    editor.ui.addHandler("zoomable_button",
    {
      create: function ()
      {
        return {
          render: function (editor, output)
          {
            output.push(html);

            return {};
          }
        };
      }
    });

    editor.on("selectionChange", function()
    {
      var sel = editor.getSelection();
      var ranges = sel.getRanges();

      if (ranges.length == 1)
      {
        var el = sel.getStartElement();

        if (el.is('img'))
        {
          enable_input();

          if (el.hasClass('zoomable'))
            check_cb();
          else
            uncheck_cb();
        }
        else
          disable_input();
      }
      else
        disable_input();
    });

    editor.on("instanceReady", function ()
    {
      cb = $('.add_zoomable_cb');
      span = $('.add_zoomable_span');

      cb.change(function()
      {
        var element = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();

        if (cb.is(':checked'))
          element.addClass('zoomable');
        else
          element.removeClass('zoomable');
      });

    });

    function enable_input()
    {
      cb.removeAttr('disabled');
      span.css('color', enabled_span_color);
    }

    function disable_input()
    {
      uncheck_cb();
      cb.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      span.css('color', disabled_span_color);
    }

    function check_cb()
    {
      cb.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }

    function uncheck_cb()
    {
      cb.removeAttr('checked');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor doesn't include the option to add a checkbox to the toolbar, so your first step is to look at their code and extend it to add the checkbox.

Then look at how other buttons work to modify the content and detect when the selection in the editor changes to reflect its new state, and apply those ideas to your checkbox.